# Compare string condition during transform operation

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe df:

```
SCHOOL CLASS GRADE
A Spanish nan
A Spanish nan
A Math    4000   
A Math    7830
A Math    3893
B .       nan
B .       nan
B Biology 1929
B Biology 4839
B Biology 8195
C Spanish nan
C English 2003
C English 1000
C Biology 4839
C Biology 8191
```

If I do:

```
school_has_only_two_classes = df.groupby('SCHOOL').CLASS
.transform(lambda series: series.nunique()) == 2
```

I get

```
0      True
1      True
2      True
3      True
4      True
5      True
6      True
7      True
8      True
9      True
10    False
11    False
12    False
13    False
14    False
15    False
```

The transform works fine for the school C. BUT, if I do:

```
school_has_spanish = df.groupby('SCHOOL').CLASS.transform(lambda series: series.str.contains('^Spanish$',regex=True))
```

or

```
school_has_spanish = df.groupby('SCHOOL').CLASS.transform(lambda series: series=='Spanish')
```

I get the following result which is not what I was expecting:

```
0      True
1      True
2     False
3     False
4     False
5     False
6     False
7     False
8     False
9     False
10     True
11    False
12    False
13    False
14    False
15    False
```

The transform just does not spread all True's to the other rows of the group. Result I was expecting:

```
0      True
1      True
2      True
3      True
4     False
5     False
6     False
7     False
8     False
9     False
10     True
11     True
12     True
13     True
14     True
15     True
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please suggest an edit before downvoting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `any` with `contains`

```
df.CLASS.str.contains('Spanish').groupby(df.SCHOOL).transform('any')
Out[230]: 
0      True
1      True
2      True
3      True
4      True
5     False
6     False
7     False
8     False
9     False
10     True
11     True
12     True
13     True
14     True
Name: CLASS, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Would you please point me to some documentation of the 'any'. I had no luck with the pandas docs on .transform

Comment: @Kaisar https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html